# Run JavaScript From Dynamically Created Links

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am creating a blog style website in which it pulls information from a database to create each post dynamically. Once all the posts have been created the header from each of the posts will open an overlaid div which brings up the whole article for that particular post.

How the posts are created...

```
<table class="mainTable">
    <tr>
        <td id="mainBanner">
            <img class="startLogo" src="images/logo.png">
        </td>

        <?php
            $sql = 'SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY Post_ID DESC';

            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

            if($result){
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        ?>
        <td class="<?php if($row['Post_Featured'] == 0) {echo 'visualPost';} else {echo 'featuredPost';} ?>" id="<?php echo $row['Post_ID']; ?>">
            <a id="openOverlay" name="<?php echo $row['Post_ID']; ?>" href="#">
                <?php echo $row['Post_Title']; ?>
            </a>
            <img src="images/<?php echo $row['Post_Image_Embed']; ?>" width="100%">
            <p><?php echo $row['Post_Blurb']; ?> Votes:<?php echo $row['Post_Votes']; ?></p>
        </td>
        <?php
                }
            }
        ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JavaScript

```
var createOverlay = document.getElementById("openOverlay");
var destroyOverlay = document.getElementById("closeOverlay");

createOverlay.onclick = toggleOverlay;
destroyOverlay.onclick = toggleOverlay;

function toggleOverlay() {
    var postID = $(this).attr('name');
    var specialBox = document.getElementById('specialBox');
    var container = document.getElementById('container');

    if (container.style.display == "block") {
        document.body.style.overflowY = "hidden";
        container.style.display = "none";
        specialBox.style.display = "none";
        $("body").mousewheel(function (event, delta) {
            this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 20);
            event.preventDefault();
        });
        $('div#postOverlay').empty();
    } else {
        document.body.style.overflowX = "hidden";
        container.style.display = "block";
        specialBox.style.display = "block";
        $("body").unmousewheel();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "overlayFill.php",
            data: { 'id': postID },
            success: function (data) {
                $('div#postOverlay').append(data);
            }
        });
    }
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

I tried using document.getElementById('openOverlay') to grab the  link and run the JavaScript needed to bring up the overlay depending on the post and running a php script to grab the information from the database and post it to the overlay but it seems like it only grabs the first dynamically created id (aka the first id getElementById hits) the rest of the posts won't bring up an overlay.

Overlay

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="specialBox">
        <a id="closeOverlay" href="#">Close</a>
        <div id="postOverlay"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a better way to do this? I thought about maybe trying a button but I thought I would end up with the same issues.

Comment: Think for a moment: You have `<a id="openOverlay">` *inside* a loop. That means you get duplicate IDs. Bad.

Comment: You should only use an `id` once per page. It looks like you're reusing it multiple times. Though browsers will let you get away with this with CSS it is bad news.

Comment: Is jQuery available/being used, as the tags suggest?

Comment: @Ted: if the question is tagged with jQuery, you're free to assume that jQuery is available until such time as the OP realises their mistake. If someone tags their question with the [tag:jquery] tag because they specifically mention that don't want jQuery then that should be evident from reading the question. And the tag should be removed by anyone that reads the question.

Comment: I used jQuery for some of the mouse events, sorry this is my first question so I didn't know whether to include it cause some mouse events are in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `<a id="openOverlay"` to `<a class="openOverlay"` (and the same with `#closeOverlay`) and use jQuery's `.on()`, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.openOverlay, .closeOverlay', toggleOverlay);
});
```

This allows the event to be bound to elements that have not been added to the dom yet.

Comment: The .openOverlay is working! I tried adding the .closeOverlay as well but it doesn't run it. Would I need to have that as a class as well? Since the container would be cleared and filled each time there is only one closeOverlay at any time.

Comment: If you want to use the ID instead--and there's only one in the dom, change the `'.openOverlay, .closeOverlay'` bit to `'.openOverlay, #closeOverlay'` and it should work fine

Comment: Okay, both ways worked! My issue was that I had each in it's own quotation marks as `'.openOverlay', '.closeOverlay'` instead of `'.openOverlay, .closeOverlay'`. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of dynamically creating the block that has another `id` attribute, you should use `class='closeOverlay'`.

Then instead of `getElementById('closeOverlay')` you can use `getElementsByClassName('closeOverlay')`, and add your function to each of element in that return array.